# how to send post data with fmx webbrowser

Tags: php, android, delphi, twebbrowser, postdata

i want to send data with Twebbrowser into web which receive by php $_post methode, then show it on webbrowser as webpage. this code is work perfectly in my vcl application

```
uses
httpapp;


Var
strData: string;
  PostData: OleVariant;
  Headers: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
  url:string;
begin    
url :='http://www.abc...com'
strData := 'id=' + HTTPEncode('ID') + '&' +
    'ik=' + HttpEncode('ID2');
PostData := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(strData) - 1], varByte);
for i := 1 to Length(strData) do
    PostData[i-1] := Ord(strData[i]);
Headers := 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' + #10#13;
WebBrowser1.Navigate(url+'/logs.php',EmptyParam,EmptyParam,PostData,Headers);
end;
```

But when i try it for fmx for android device application, it send me eror message "too many actual parameter" on webbrowser.navigate. how can i post data with fmx webbrowser for fmx / android application ?

Comment: I suggest you check the line for i := 1 to Length(strData) do
    PostData[i-1] := Ord(strData[i]); because Fmx rather then VCL uses one based array and VCL uses zero based array. Replace '''for i := 1 to Length(strData) do
    PostData[i-1] := Ord(strData[i]);''' for '''for i := 1 to Length(strData) do
    PostData[i] := Ord(strData[i]);''' peace of code. I didn't check. I just remember I had this problem in past.

Comment: I have run it on vcl application and its working, but error too many parameter on navigate at fmx webbrowser,, so i think the problem is there is no parameter can input on fmx.webbrowser.navigate,, it just url link can add in..

Comment: `OleVariant` and `Android` doesn't sound like a workable combination (`OLE` is a `Windows` thing). And `FMX.WebBrowser.Navigate` method takes none, or only one parameter, `(const AURL: string)`. Therefore the error.

Comment: Yup, its only one parameter(url). So, is there other way to send post data and show it at webbrowser? Is twebbrowser doesn't support posting data to php? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own html that includes the forum and post action and have javascript that auto-posts the form for you and then just call TWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings to load the html from a string var.

```
MyWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings({$I 'html\string_login_by_code.html.inc'},strSiteBaseURL);
```

And the "html\string_login_by_code.html.inc" file would look like:

```
'<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>'+
'<script>'+
'window.onload = function() '+
'  {'+
'    document.getElementById("v_login").submit();'+
'  }'+
'</script>'+
'<form id="v_login" style="display:none" method="post" action="'+PostURL+'">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="'+chUserName+'" value="'+sUserName+'">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="'+chPassword+'" value="'+sPassword+'">'+
'<input type="submit" class="menu_submit" value="&nbsp;">'+
'</form>'+
'</BODY></HTML>'
```

Comment: There is another action on loaded webpage, like a edit or delete action,, if i use webbrowser.loadfromstrings, i think the action won't works..

Comment: You just take parts of the webpage to replicate the desired automated form action, fill in the fields you want yourself and then auto-submit it using javascript like in the example I gave.

Comment: wow, its good idea, i have tried your trick and its working.. thanks..